# How to fix PHP/HTML suggestions box

Tags: php, html, forms

I have been trying to make a simple suggestions box

**HTML from .html page**

```
<form action="suggestions.php">
Suggest some content for this page: <input type="text" name="suggestion"></br>
</br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

**PHP from suggestions.php page**

```
<?php

$filename = date('Format String');
$Content = $_POST["suggestion"];
file_put_contents('./suggestions/'.$filename, $Content);

?>
```

**What it should do**

- Allow anonymous input of suggestions
- Create file with suggestions in "suggestions" directory
- Name file as date and time to the second

Comment: What is yip our issue other than the get/post mismatch? If you use $_request instead of $_post you can use either

Comment: Why are you not just using a database?

Answer (score 2):

The default form method is `GET`. You need `method="POST"` in your form tag, like so:

```
<form action="suggestions.php" method="POST">
Suggest some content for this page: <input type="text" name="suggestion"><br>
```